# How do I prompt for user input in AutoHotkey?

Tags: user-input, autohotkey

I'm writing an AutoHotkey script which needs to retrieve typed user input as a string. (Username, password, filename, etc.)

How do I retrieve user input with AutoHotkey?

Comment: Related: [How can I read multiple lines of user input in AutoHotkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986293/how-can-i-read-multiple-lines-of-user-input-in-autohotkey)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can use AutoHotkey's built in [InputBox](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputBox.htm).**

```
InputBox, UserInput, Enter Name, Please enter a username:, , 300, 150
MsgBox, You entered %UserInput% as your username
```

[image: Input box for a username]

---

Here's an excerpt from the [InputBox documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputBox.htm)

> ### [InputBox](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputBox.htm)
>
> Displays an input box to ask the user to enter a string.
>
> ```
> InputBox, OutputVar [, Title, Prompt, HIDE, Width, Height, X, Y, Font, Timeout, Default]
> ```
>
> #### Remarks
>
> The dialog allows the user to enter text and then press OK or CANCEL. The user can resize the dialog window by dragging its borders.
>
> #### Example
>
> ```
> InputBox, password, Enter Password, (your input will be hidden), hide 
> InputBox, UserInput, Phone Number, Please enter a phone number., , 640, 480
> if ErrorLevel
>     MsgBox, CANCEL was pressed.
> else
>     MsgBox, You entered "%UserInput%"
> ```

***Source***: [Autohotkey documentation for InputBox](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputBox.htm)

Answer (score 3):

For username and password you can go with what Stevoisiak offered. but for filename, it's rather cruel to require users to enter filepath.

Better go with [FileSelectFile](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileSelectFile.htm) or [FileSelectFolder](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileSelectFolder.htm) (it's official documentation links with examples).

Also, if you need to ask several items, instead of displaying separate input boxes sequentially, it's much better to make a gui. Fortunately, it's not burdensome in AutoHotkey:

```
    Gui Add, Text, xm section, login
    Gui Add, Edit, ys x100 W300 vlogin, %defaultLogin%
    Gui Add, Text, xm section, password
    Gui Add, Edit, ys x100 W300 Password vpassword
    Gui Add, Text, xm section, File: 
    Gui Add, Edit, ys x100 W300 vusrSelFile
    Gui Add, Button, ys, Browse
    Gui Add, Button, section Default, OK
    Gui Add, Button, ys gExit, Cancel
    Gui Show
Exit

ButtonOK:
    Gui Submit
    ;Gui Submit, NoHide if you wanna check contrains and let user fix their input
    MsgBox,
        (LTrim
        login: %login%
        password: %password%
        file: %usrSelFile%
        )
ExitApp
        
    
ButtonBrowse:
    FileSelectFile fPath
    GuiControl,, usrSelFile, %fPath%
return

GuiClose:
Exit:
    ExitApp

GuiDropFiles: ; you can also let users drop files on the GUI window
Loop Parse, A_GuiEvent, `n
{
    GuiControl,, usrSelFile, %A_LoopField%
    return ; only first dropped file selected, others ignored
}
return ; in case the event been triggered with no files in list
```