# How can I read multiple lines of user input in AutoHotkey?

Tags: user-input, autohotkey

I have an AutoHotkey script which needs to read multiple lines of employee data from a user.

```
InputBox, userInput, Employee Records, Please enter employee records. (One per line)
```

Unfortunately, an [InputBox](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputBox.htm) only allows users to enter a single line of text. Trying to add newlines with <kbd>Enter</kbd> will instead submit whatever data has been entered.

**How can I take in multiple lines of user input in an AutoHotkey script?**

[image: user input]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This implements a generic multiline input function**

```
F3::MsgBox % MultiLineInput( "Employee Records", "Please enter employee records (One per line):" )

MultiLineInput(title, prompt)
{
  static input
  input := ""
  Gui, Add, Text,, %prompt%
  Gui, Add, Edit, w400 h60 vinput
  Gui, Add, Button, gokay_pressed, Okay
  Gui, Add, Button, cancel X+8 YP+0, Cancel
  Gui, Show, Center autosize, %title%
  WinWaitClose %title%
  return input

  okay_pressed:
    Gui Submit
    Gui Destroy
    return

  GuiClose:
  GuiEscape:
  ButtonCancel:
    Gui, Destroy
    return
}
```

Comment: Bound variables need to be static or global

Comment: MultiLineInput() returns the user's input as a string even when Cancel has been selected.

Comment: Would you be interested in hosting this as a library on GitHub? I have found myself using this function quite often and would love to help develop it further.

Comment: Feel free to use, modify and publish the code however and wherever you want. Thanks for asking

Answer (score 2):

**This demonstrates a multi-line input box**

```
F2::
  Gui, Add, Text,, Please enter employee records (One per line):
  Gui, Add, Edit, w600 h60 vinput
  Gui, Add, Button, gokay_pressed, Okay
  Gui, Add, Button, cancel X+8 YP+0, Cancel
  Gui, Show, Center autosize, Employee Records
  Return

okay_pressed:
  Gui Submit
  Gui Destroy
  MsgBox %input%
  Return

GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
ButtonCancel:
  Gui, Destroy
  return
```

[image]